# Apache Zookeeper Curator Framework with AMQP

Tags: apache-zookeeper, amqp, spring-amqp, apache-curator

I am new to AMQP , but I want to get an experience with AMQP with Curator Framework on Apache Zookeeper, So please let me know if you have a link for Github sample project and useful information to understand this.

Comment: Sorry, your question isn't clear. Tell us, please, who said you that you really should use AMQP and ZK together. Please, read about each of them separately from their official resources and try to figure what would you do to mix them. And only after that come back with questions.

Comment: It's required to register the services into Zookeeper to pass messages between the microservices

Comment: Who is that? Please, don't be spy. If you would like to get as much as possible help, share info as it is. Thanks to the subject we don't talk here about the business, just architecture. We need Zookeeper to ensure cluster consistency for many instances of our application. We need AMQP really to send messages between different applications. That's why I sent you to read original sources on the matter and distinguish topics.

Comment: What you explained here was very high level about Zookeeper and AMQP but I want to replace Zookeeper distributed Queue with AMQP using RabbitMQ. Please understand the need of this integration then reply back